How to add controls through code in winforms dynamically
I am developing an application for storing books, movies, comics etc using c# and MySQL[for myself]
In my view form, I want to be able to view all of it in a way similar to how Netflix does it[without desc-titles above and a flowlayout that goes left to right].
|| What I have tried||
To try to achieve this, I created a class that holds a flow layout panel, label and a picture box.
 public class ViewObjectClass
 {
     public Label Label { get; set; }
     public FlowLayoutPanel FlowLayoutPanel { get; set; }
     public PictureBox pictureBox { get; set; }


 }

Then I created a function that takes in another class that holds data I wanted to insert into the control.
public ViewObjectClass CreateSeries(DataClass Data)
{
    ViewObjectClass viewObjectClass = new ViewObjectClass();

    viewObjectClass.pictureBox.Width = 130;
    viewObjectClass.pictureBox.Height = 180;
    viewObjectClass.pictureBox.ImageLocation = Data.C_Image;
    viewObjectClass.pictureBox.SizeMode=PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    viewObjectClass.Label.Text = Data.C_Title;
    viewObjectClass.FlowLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;
    viewObjectClass.FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(viewObjectClass.pictureBox);
    viewObjectClass.FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(viewObjectClass.Label);
    return viewObjectClass;
}

It returns the controls and I add them to my view
DataAccesObject accesObject = new DataAccesObject();
public View()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    accesObject.Collection = accesObject.GetAllCollection(); //Collection is a list of Dataclass
    for (int i = 0; i < accesObject.Collection.Count; i++) 
    {
      accesObject.ViewObjectClass = accesObject.CreateSeries(accesObject.Collection[i]);
        this.Controls.Add(accesObject.ViewObjectClass.FlowLayoutPanel);
        accesObject.ViewObjectClass.FlowLayoutPanel.MouseClick +=     Mouseclicked(accesObject.ViewObjectClass.Label.Text);
      
    }
    
}

The problem I am having is that I am unable to modify the control before adding them to the view,I am also really sure that there are many more problems outside of it that I am not able to view thx to the first problem.

Do not quite understand the problem. If the data you want to show via the ViewObjectClass is in the DataClass then just move the data over or connect those via the databinding feature. Do you know about Custom Controls? Your combination of controls in ViewObjectClass shouts to me that you want that to be a Custom Control.

You might want to correct the shown code it won't work besides your mentioned problem. For example the Controls inside ViewObjectClass  aren't created but you use them in code.

Why not create a UserControl? Then you can design them at designtime (with all controls) and still create it dynamically at runtime.

My Bad, i meant control not data

Well, you can put viewobject.pictureBox.Location = new Point(i*100, 200); inside the loop and it will place them in a line.

The solution to this problem is to create a userControl,add public variables to the usercontrols that set the values of the controls inside the usercontrol.Then add it to the form.
public partial class SeriesPanel : UserControl


public SeriesPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private string _ImageLocation;
private string _Title;
private Image _Icon;
[Category("Custom Props")]
public string ImageLocation
{
    get { return _ImageLocation; }
    set { _ImageLocation = value; PanelImage.ImageLocation = value; }
}
[Category("Custom Props")]
public string Title
{
    get { return _Title; }
    set { _Title = value; PanelLabel.Text = value; }

}
[Category("Custom Props")]
public Image Icon
{
    get { return _Icon; }
    set { _Icon = value; PanelImage.Image = value; }
}

Then in my form I created a function that I call x amount of times which will add and set everything for me.
 private void AddPanels(DataClass Data)

 {SeriesPanel seriesPanel = new SeriesPanel();
 seriesPanel.ImageLocation = Data.C_Image;
 seriesPanel.Title = Data.C_Title;
 this.Controls.Add(seriesPanel);
 seriesPanel.MouseClick += Mouseclicked(Data.C_Title);}

the only problem I have found with this is that the mouseclick event happens the moment I create it,which is really annoying >:(
